# Trouble with gif export output with transparent background in gimp

Tags: gimp, gif

So I took a gif, and edited out the background for each frame.

When I go to filters -> animation -> playback it plays the gif perfectly fine with a transparent background.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vce0E.jpg

After exporting the gif and opening it up on an image viewer, the background is gone, but instead of it being transparent, it's turned into a white background.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/70E5Y.jpg

I've tried using optimize for gif, but it doesn't change anything. I also have tried exporting the gif as both png and gif format.

Comment: Are you sure the background is white? Maybe the image viewer just displays the transparent part in a white color. Try to open the gif in Gimp again. Also please *embed* the original images, and not just (overly large) screenshots.

Comment: You say "opening it up on an image viewer" - but you don't say which one. Not all image viewers support transparency. Have you tried viewing the GIF in a browser, where GIFs are meant to be viewed?

Answer (score 1):

Works for me, different viewers (Firefox, Gwenview), different backgrounds, so Gimp encodes transparent pixels:

[image: Exemple image]

However, remember that in a GIF, there is no partial transparency, so you won't get smooth edges (the circles are smooth in the original image, but jagged in the GIF). To get smooth edges, you have to use [*Filters>Web/Semi-flatten*](https://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-semiflatten.html), but this works only for a specific background color.

Edit: You can insert your image into some html that sets a specific background and look at the result by loading the resulting file in your navigator:

```
<html>
<body>
<!--<div style="background-color: #00ff00"> -->
<div style="background-image: url(pattern.png)">
<img src=TransparentAnim.gif />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you see the background behind your image, then you image is good and whatever unexpected background you get is from the image viewer or the web site and not from your image.